# Can I read data from passive segments in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose that for a partition I have segments like this;

- Segment-0 -> start offset:0, end offset:1087
- Segment-1 -> start offset:1088 end offset:2300
- Segment-2 (Active segment) -> start offset:2301, ...

In consumer side can I seek to offset 1100 or the minimum offset that I can seek from is 2301?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can seek anywhere in the topic. Segments are a server detail not exposed to clients

For example, `--from-beginning` on the console consumer would be offset 0, not the start of the active segment.

Comment: What if segment-0 is deleted because of retention policy? Will the offset be 1088 with `--from-beginning` parameter?  Also if I try to seek to offset 100 after deletion of segment-0, will it throw an exception?

Comment: It'll always seek to the next available offset. It might log an error, but not throw an exception